# Bootstrap 4 - Row of inputs 1% larger than full width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have a simple form I've been messing with:

```
<div class="container">
    <form name="form" method="post">

    <div class="form-row mt-5">
        <div class="col-3">
            <label class="sr-only form-control-label required" for="form_column_name">Column Name</label>
            <select id="form_column_name" name="form[column_name]" class="form-control-lg form-control"><option value="Field 1" selected="selected">Field 1</option><option value="Field 2">Field 2</option></select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8">
            <label class="sr-only form-control-label required" for="form_column_value">Column Value</label>
            <input type="text" id="form_column_value" name="form[column_value]" required="required" class="form-control-lg form-control" placeholder="Query" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button">Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div class="progress" style="height: 25px;">
                <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-12">
            <table class="table" width="101%">
                <thead class="thead-light">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Username</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="n0n-XzlZGwNC4-GUi8PiM5UYC25lSx_vMg7qwI7OPSg" />
</form>
</div>
```

It's a Symfony 3 Twig template, and it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the inputs are just slightly longer than the other elements, even though everything is at `col-12`.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I can set the progress bar to `width: 101%`, but I couldn't figure out the how to change the table. Also it feels a little hacky, so I'm wondering if there is a better solution.

Additionally, using `container-fluid` causes the size difference to change:

[image]

So I'm assuming I've setup the `form` wrong. I've tried using `form-inline`, but couldn't get the margins and centring to work that way either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to reset padding on the button and give it a width:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pr-0 pl-0 w-100" type="button">Search</button>
```

demo below to play in full page

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <form name="form" method="post" >

    <div class="form-row mt-5">
      <div class="col-3">
        <label class="sr-only form-control-label required" for="form_column_name">Column Name</label>
        <select id="form_column_name" name="form[column_name]" class="form-control-lg form-control"><option value="Field 1" selected="selected">Field 1</option><option value="Field 2">Field 2</option></select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <label class="sr-only form-control-label required" for="form_column_value">Column Value</label>
        <input type="text" id="form_column_value" name="form[column_value]" required="required" class="form-control-lg form-control" placeholder="Query" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-1" style="flex-shrink:1">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pr-0 pl-0 w-100" type="button">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="progress" style="height: 25px;">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-12">
        <table class="table" width="101%">
          <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">First Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="n0n-XzlZGwNC4-GUi8PiM5UYC25lSx_vMg7qwI7OPSg" />
  </form>
</div>
```

you can also add responsive class to let room to the button text:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-7"> 

<div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2">
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <form name="form" method="post" class="m-0">

    <div class="form-row mt-5">
      <div class="col-3">
        <label class="sr-only form-control-label required" for="form_column_name">Column Name</label>
        <select id="form_column_name" name="form[column_name]" class="form-control-lg form-control"><option value="Field 1" selected="selected">Field 1</option><option value="Field 2">Field 2</option></select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-7">
        <label class="sr-only form-control-label required" for="form_column_value">Column Value</label>
        <input type="text" id="form_column_value" name="form[column_value]" required="required" class="form-control-lg form-control" placeholder="Query" />
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-2" style="flex-shrink:1">
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pr-0 pl-0 w-100" type="button">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="progress" style="height: 25px;">
          <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-animated" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 100%"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mt-3">
      <div class="col-12">
        <table class="table" width="101%">
          <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">First Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Username</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="n0n-XzlZGwNC4-GUi8PiM5UYC25lSx_vMg7qwI7OPSg" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Changing the `button` class worked perfectly. Thanks for the assist.